# Convert this Linq query from query syntax to lambda expression

Tags: linq, lambda, linq-query-syntax

I'm not sure I like linq query syntax...its just not my preference.  But I don't know what this query would look like using lambda expressions, can someone help?

```
from securityRoles in user.SecurityRoles
from permissions in securityRoles.Permissions
where permissions.SecurableEntity.Name == "Unit" && permissions.PermissionType.Name == "Read"
orderby permissions.PermissionLevel.Value descending
select permissions
```

There is a many-to-many relationship between users and security roles that makes this extra confusing.

Thanks!
Kelly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
user.SecurityRoles.SelectMany(securityRoles => securityRoles.Permissions)
                  .Where(permissions => permissions.SecurableEntity.Name == "Unit" && permissions.PermissionType.Name == "Read")
                  .OrderByDescending(permissions => permissions.PermissionLevel.Value)
```

Comment: ReSharper has a nice feature that automatically translates query syntax to 'method chain' and (sometimes) vice versa. [note: I'm not related to jetbrains]

Answer (score 1):

```
        user.SecurityRoles.SelectMany(securityRoles => securityRoles.Permissions,
                                      (securityRoles, permissions) => new {securityRoles, permissions}).Where(
            @t => permissions.SecurableEntity.Name == "Unit" && permissions.PermissionType.Name == "Read").OrderByDescending(
            @t => permissions.PermissionLevel.Value).Select(@t => permissions)
```